# How and where to make API requests that depend on the response of another request?

Tags: reactjs, redux, action

I have to compose several API requests, I am using redux.

For the sake of simplicity let's say there are 2.

When I obtain the response from request A, I use response.data.param, and make request B.

Should this be done where I make the API requests, making

```
requestA
  .then(res => requestB(res.data.param))
```

Or in the component where I dispatch the actions?

```
dispatch(A())
  .then(res => dispatch(B(res.data.param)))
```

or in the actions?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

It depends totally on the use case. If your UI is reflecting the response of request A, while B is loading, it is better to dispatch on component, e.g. some progress level. If UI depends on both, then it is better to call them just one after another in reducer only.

Comment: thank you, no, I will not show the response of A, A only gets called to get the parameters for B, if I do not need B, I do not need to call A either, so should I concatenate on making the requests or in the actions?

Comment: Then those are inherently bound to single logic and you can call them in chain. That way you dont have to write two reducers as well.